# Count word - unique times from a column of strings

Tags: python, string

I have created a dummy data set below with ID and text column which has string column containing names of some companies.

```
  # create dummy data frame with text columns
    x=[1,2,3,4,5]
    y=['apple google microsoft spotify alibaba','google microsoft','spotify google microsoft amazon','amazon google apple','amazon google spotify amazon']
    df=pd.DataFrame({'ID':x,'text':y})
    df
```

I have another list which also has names of companies

```
# create list of companies
listtry=['apple','google','microsoft','spotify','alibaba','amazon','structo']
```

what i want to do is count the number of rows in which each of the company occurs in the main dataframe text column and not the actual count of occurrences across strings of text column

Below code gives actual occurrences count

```
    # search amd count 
df2 = list()
for company in listtry :
    df2.append(df.text.str.count(company).sum())
df3=pd.DataFrame({'company':listtry,'count':df2})
df4=df3.sort_values('count',ascending=False)
df4

# gives results

     company  count
1     google      5
5     amazon      4
2  microsoft      3
3    spotify      3
0      apple      2
4    alibaba      1
6    structo      0
```

Expected output is Amazon should be 3 times only as it occurs in 3 rows only but is occuring twice in the last string and hence is count total is 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another try , change `count` to `contains` and take the length of df:

```
for company in listtry :
    df2.append(len(df[df.text.str.contains(company)]))  # only changes here
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `set` to remove the duplicates? (See the 3rd line)

```
   x=[1,2,3,4,5]
   y=['apple google microsoft spotify alibaba','google microsoft','spotify google microsoft 
   amazon','amazon google apple','amazon google spotify amazon']
   y=[' '.join(set(yy.split(' '))) for yy in y] 
   df=pd.DataFrame({'ID':x,'text':y})
```

Comment: Yes a possible approach, but my strings in variable Y in actual data are huge articles. Pre-processing them to get unique words would make it more time consuming.